# Devise: Some users on iOS keeps getting signed out, when they leave the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I run a pretty simple rails 5.1 app with turbolinks where I use devise 4.4 for authentication. I have setup `rememberable` for devise, and it works well for most of my users. But for some with (iOS only so far, and not all) the remember me functionality does not work. After they have signed in and correctly checked the "remember me" checkbox, they get signed out as soon as they have left the browser (e.g. switched to another app than safari) for a couple of minutes.

The key files looks as follows:

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'webmaster@example.com'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.remember_for = 1.year
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.extend_remember_period = true
  config.password_length = 6..128
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
  config.timeout_in = 2.weeks
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :get
end
```

sessions/new.slim:

```
h2
  | Log in
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  .field
    = f.input :email, autofocus: true, type: "email"
  .field
    = f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", type: 'passsword'
  - if devise_mapping.rememberable?
    .field
      = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean
  .actions
    = f.submit "Log in", class: 'btn btn-primary'
br
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

I have no idea why this happens, what could cause it and how to debug it?

Comment: The only thing that stands out to me is `config.sign_out_via = :get`. It should be via `:delete`. I wonder if your iOS users are hitting `sessions#destroy` instead of `create`. Not sure why only some of your users would experience that, but in any case, destroying a session should be done via `:delete` requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I have found out what goes wrong. Some of my iOS users had bookmarked my app on their homescreen. More specifically they had bookmarked the login screen. So whenever they opened up the app through the bookmark, it would try to authorise them, and eventually log them out.